# Does WOL require two both systems to be connected to the same SSID?

Tags: wake-on-lan

I'm trying to get WOL to work on my computer and I followed many different instructions from many sites and even with my network card set up for WOL and WOL enabled in BIOS, I can't​get the system to wake up when I send a packet from my other computer. The computer I'm trying to wake up is connected VIA Ethernet while my other computer is wireless. Do they need to be on the same network SSID? The SSID for 5g Ethernet (modem default) and 5g (custom) wireless are different but would that effect anything? I know the network card is online when the computer is asleep because the LED light is blinking and everything seems okay with it.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you specifically enabled some form of "subnet directed broadcasts" the WOL packet must be sent by a computer on the same LAN (subnet). Source: [Wake-on-LAN - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz On consumer routers in my experience, the wireless devices and Ethernet connected devices are all in the same subnet.

Comment: Yes, but there are many other ways two device can be on the same subnet. They can be connected to different routers on that same subnet. Or they can be connected to different SSIDs on one router that shares a subnet. (For example, routers that have different SSIDs for 2.4GHz and 5Ghz but in the same broadcast domain and subnet.)

Comment: @David If they're connected to different _routers_, that'll result in different subnets almost by definition...

Comment: @grawity David is right.  For example, you can have two routers connected LAN port-to-LAN port in the same subnet (used for expanding a WiFi network with a second router).

Comment: @grawity So VPNs don't exist? And a single network can't have a dozen routers connected to it?

Comment: Routers when performing their *routing* function create separate broadcast domains, which WoL packets cannot cross in a default configuration. Consumer wireless "routers" that put the wireless and wired interfaces in the same broadcast domain aren't routing between the interfaces, they're bridging them, which doesn't split the broadcast domain. Connecting two residential routers LAN-to-LAN port from a networking perspective is connecting two *switches*, since the packets never get routed to a different subnetwork, so again there's only one broadcast domain.

Answer (score 2):

> The SSID for 5g Ethernet

Um, "5g Ethernet"? SSID? Ethernet is a plain wired connection and neither of those terms make any sense for it. (The "5g" means 5 GHz *radio* frequencies.)

---

That said, the connection type is not important as long as both devices are in the same *broadcast domain* – or generally, in the same subnet. So take a look at their IP addresses (when both are awake) and check if they have identical prefixes.

*(If you 'stack' routers, additional caveats apply.)*

Most home routers *will* attach all WiFi SSIDs and Ethernet ports to the same subnet. However it's not guaranteed; some have it configurable in various ways.

---

The other issue is whether your device will *react* to WOL packets. It has to be enabled for both Ethernet interfaces (via Device Manager and perhaps even the power profile) and WiFi adapters (see Hefewe1zen's answer). Even if enabled *everywhere*, it might only work for suspend-to-memory (and sometimes hibernation), but not if the computer is powered off.

Answer (score 1):

Your device must support wake on wireless LAN.  If it does, then you can set the registry key as per this article https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851581(v=WS.10).aspx

More technical info here : http://revolutionwifi.blogspot.com/2010/11/wake-on-wireless-lan.html

```
To enable WoWLAN support for GTK and EAP scenarios
To enable WoWLAN support for GTK and EAP scenarios, create or modify the following registry key:
Key Name: EnableWoWLAN

Type: DWORD

Path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NativeWifiP\Parameters

Value: 1

In addition to modifying this registry key, you must also configure the network device in the Device Manager.
Open Device Manager.

Right-click the network card you want to configure and select Device Properties.

In the Power Management tab, select the Allow this device to wake up the computer check box.
```